# How to stop Jupyterlab 4.0.1 from truncating a pandas multiindex output?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, jupyter-lab

I have a system generated Excel dataset that is created with a poorly defined multilevel header.  I am trying to clean up the header by using a multiIndex from Pandas.  My multiIndex has 480x tuples with 4 elements (levels) in each tuple.  I want to be able to view the entire multiIndex in Jupyterlab 4.0.1 but anything greater than 41 tuples it starts to truncate.

I want to view the entire multiIndex

mi1   or   mi1[:]           # This truncates to 2 elements in each tuples and only shows the first and last 10x tuples

```
MultiIndex([(                 'Quote',                      nan, ...),
            (                     nan,                      nan, ...),
            ('Location Details A-End',                      nan, ...),
```

mi1[:41]                          # This shows all 4 elements in the tuples

```
MultiIndex([(                 'Quote', nan, nan,                   'Quote ID'),
            (                     nan, nan, nan,                   'Revision'),
            ('Location Details A-End', nan, nan,                     'Loc ID'),
```

mi1[:42]                         # Greater than 42 truncates to 3 elements but will show as many as 100 tuples

```
MultiIndex([(                 'Quote',      nan, nan, ...),
            (                     nan,      nan, nan, ...),
            ('Location Details A-End',      nan, nan, ...),
```